# Why is my Java applet just displaying my fallback message?

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

My Java Applet is just displaying the fallback message in all my browsers. I have got:

- Google Chrome
- Microsoft Edge
- Internet Explorer

Here is the code for the applet:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LottoApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    // Components
    ClassLoader ldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    java.net.URL iconURL = ldr.getResource( "Lotto.png" );
    ImageIcon icon  = new ImageIcon( iconURL );
    JLabel img      = new JLabel( icon );
    JTextField txt  = new JTextField( "", 18 );
    JButton btn     = new JButton( "Get My Lucky Numbers" );
    JPanel pnl      = new JPanel();

    // Applet entry point
    public void init()
    {
        pnl.add( img );
        pnl.add( txt );
        pnl.add( btn );
        btn.addActionListener( this );
        String bgStr = getParameter( "BgColor" );
        int bgHex = Integer.parseInt( bgStr, 16 );
        pnl.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( bgHex ));
        add( pnl );
    }

    // Event-handler
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
        if( event.getSource() == btn )
        {
            // Declare working variables.
            int[] nums = new int[60];
            String str = "";

            // Fill elements 1-59 with integers 1-59.
            for( int i = 1; i < 60; i++ ) { nums[i] = i; }

            // Shuffle the values in elements 1-59.
            for( int i = 1; i < 60; i++ )
            {
                int r = (int) Math.ceil( 59 * Math.random() ) + 1;
                int temp=nums[i]; nums[i]=nums[r]; nums[r]=temp;
            }

            // Display the values in elements one to six.
            for ( int i = 1; i < 7; i++ )
            {
                str += "  " + Integer.toString( nums[ i ]) + "  ";

            }
            txt.setText( str );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <title>Lotto Applet Host</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <object type = "application/x-java-applet" width = "260" height = "160">
   <param name = "code" value = "LottoApplet.class">
   <param name = "BgColor" value = "FFFF00">
   <param name = "archive" value = "LottoApplet.jar">
   [ Java Applet - Requires Java Plugin ]
  </object>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have got the code from 'Java in Easy Steps', so it should be reliable. Is it just because my browsers are not supporting it?

Comment: Does any of your test browsers have java plugin installed?  Is it enabled?

Comment: Most browser will stop (or already have stopped?) supporting plugins, so Java applets will - finally - be relegated to the dumpster of history. You might want to consider not learning about them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the advice, I might not go into them.

Comment: @AleksG I have Java enabled in the browsers in the Control Panel, but if I go to [https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-java-installed](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-java-installed), it says that I don't have it enabled.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel *"Most browser will stop (or already have stopped?) supporting plugins,"* Yep. This is the reason. Many older tutorials will still fool newbies into wasting time on applets (we are still dealing with newbies using tutorials based around AWT components!) but applets are dead.